# How to start a gnome-terminal without loading profile (like bash --noprofile --norc)

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc, .profile

Can I start a gnome-terminal without loading profile?
(just like `bash --noprofile --norc`)

Sometime I made mistake in writing `.bashrc` and find no way (except `ssh` from another machine) to access that `.bashrc` to revise it.

Comment: Could you try `gnome-terminal -x bash --noprofile --norc`, please? I am not sure if this will launch Bash normally first before executing the noprofile/norc Bash session.

Answer (score 0):

You can always switch to default provide via `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Default` command ( unless you deleted that profile , of course ).